# Can i create Azure AD user account in cloud, then sync over to on-premised Azure?

Tags: azure

Is it possible to create the Azure AD user account in cloud first using the federated domain? Then sync the user account to on-premised Azure.

If i provide the onPremisesImmutableId when create the user, will this onPremisesImmutableId later create and store in on-premised azure?

Comment: Is on-premise Azure like Azure Stack or do you mean on-premise Windows Server Active Directory?

Comment: Have you already check the official documentation from Microsoft? like the one here which says:  [Integrate on-premises Active Directory domains with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/identity/azure-ad)

Comment: It is on-premise Windows Server Active Directory. User account created in on-premised windows server AD was able to sync to Azure AD cloud, eg: I create a user account in on-premised windows server AD, same account will automatically created in Azure AD cloud. However, i am asking if i create the account in Azure AD cloud, will it auto create the same account in on-premised windows server AD?